# Cocoa NSStatusBar Global HotKey

Tags: cocoa, hotkeys

I have created an NSStatusBar cocoa application which sits in the system status bar.

I want to assign a hotkey so that when pressed it toggles my applications and show the menu.

Is this possible?, In my searching and experimenting I have found a few different ways of assigning global hot keys that can be pressed when your application is in the background but I can't find any way to problematically make the menu show.

Is this possible?, If anyone thinks a way of assigning a global hotkey is best please post it.

Thanks.

---

One of the hotkey tutorials I found was on http://dbachrach.com/blog/2005/11/program-global-hotkeys-in-cocoa-easily/ for anyone interested.

Comment: There is no reason to display a menu unless it's been clicked on or "torn off."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is [an actual hotkey API](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/RegisterEventHotKey), which still exists in Snow Leopard and is available in 64-bit. It's designed specifically for this purpose, unlike the NSEvent methods, which are essentially just a block-based wrapper around CGEventTaps.

The difference is that the NSEvent methods (or CGEventTaps directly) make you look at *every* event that comes in, whereas the hotkey API only calls your function when the user presses *your* hotkey.

Comment: Thank you, that works great, Do you know if its possible to popup the apps menu via code?

Comment: Craig: Yes. See Dave DeLong's comment on his answer.

Comment: JFYI: Right now Apple marks this methods as obsolete, so they should not be used anymore

Answer (score 16):

If you're targeting 10.6+, there's some new API for `NSEvent` that can do global hotkeys.  For more information, check out this awesome blog post: http://cocoakids.net/global-hotkeys-in-cocoa-on-snow-leopard

**EDIT (a long time later)**

Tooting my own horn a bit: I could never get things like PTHotKey and other libraries to work the way I was expecting, so I eventually gave up and wrote my own HotKey wrapper.  It has a very simple API (you give it a key code, modifiers, a target, and an action), that even supports fun things like 10.6's blocks.  You can download the source here:  http://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey

Comment: Thanks for the blog post, it works great but I think il use the other example so that it works in 10.5 aswell, Do you know if its possible to popup the apps menu via code?

Comment: @Craig you can do `[myStatusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:[myStatusItem menu]]`, although that won't highlight your statusitem (which is lame).  The only other thing I'd suggest might be to fake a click over the statusitem.

Comment: http://cocoakids.net/global-hotkeys-in-cocoa-on-snow-leopard takes you to a parked domain, now.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Using the NSEvent event-monitor methods for hotkeys isn't as good, anyway, since you get *every* key event and have to match the key yourself. Better to use Carbon Events (see my answer) or one of the wrappers, such as DDHotKey.

Comment: @PeterHosey I was referring to the link used in this answer, which is now not taking to anywhere.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I know. The linked post was about the NSEvent event-monitor methods.

Comment: @PeterHosey I got that, but I was just pointing out that the first half if the answer is not anymore helpful, as it is referring a rotten link. I was not saying which method is preferable.