# Capture key press events while NSMenu is open

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenu, nsevent

I'm interested in capturing key presses while a `NSMenu` is open. For example, if the menu is open and the user presses "e", or "1" on the keyboard, send a particular message (preferably passing an event object which contains reference to which key was pressed).

I've looked into alternate menus, but I'm under the impression that can only be used to capture the option key.

Currently I'm not using any custom views, just `NSStatusBar` (where the menu spawns from) and `NSMenu`.

I'm new to Objective-C so my apologies if I'm wording anything incorrectly.

Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score -2):

I assume you are searching for this: [Cocoa NSStatusBar Global HotKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657659/cocoa-nsstatusbar-global-hotkey)