# addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask doesn't capture global keypresses

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a **status bar app**. I'm using this code to capture very user's key press in the system:

```
_keybordEventMonitor = 
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSKeyDownMask) handler:^(NSEvent        *incomingEvent)
{
    [self inputKeyboardEventHandler: incomingEvent];
}];
```

It captures everything fine, but doesn't capture global system hotkeys like <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

Accessibility APIs are enabled. Any ideas?

PS: I tried using `CGEventTap` and it's kind of works, but had it's own problems and since I'm a cocoa noob, I prefer to keep things simple for now.

Comment: The Cocoa-level event handling APIs don't provide all of the features of the lower-level APIs, and when you run into one of the limitations, there's no way around it, short of dropping down to CGEventTap (or Carbon events). There are a number of Cocoa wrappers around CGEventTap; would you be interested in doing things that way, so you don't have to deal with the CoreFoundation-level stuff?

Comment: We've already shipped the app with `CGEventTap`s, but I'm still interested in the higher level solution.

Comment: The higher level APIs are incomplete, so there is no complete higher level solution. Among the things you can't do are capture global system hotkeys, media keys, mouse tracking outside of all app windows, and so on. If you want to do these things from a higher level, you either have to write a wrapper around CGEventTap (or Carbon Events), or find a third-party one, because there is no way to do it build into Cocoa.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657659/cocoa-nsstatusbar-global-hotkey

Comment: Thanks. Could you please write it as an answer so I can award you with bounty?